# Alternative to VB.NET's Type Conversion functions (CBool) in C#?

Tags: .net, vb.net, type-conversion, vb.net-to-c#

Is there any alternative to VB's [`CBool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) keyword in C#?

What about all the other functions?

`CBool` will turn to a Boolean any valid boolean: `0`, `"False"`, `null` etc.

Comment: @Vladislav: that is not the same thing. You can't have `(bool)1` in C#, while `CBool(1)` will be perfectly legal in VB.NET.

Comment: CBool not only turns valid boolean values into booleans. After All there's only two such valid values. It interprets the given value and if successful returns either true or false. Which is why it's different than a cast which would only work on valid boolean values

Comment: I just tried it out and a `cast` is apparently not so "smart" as I would have thought :) `System.Convert` is the way to go.

Comment: @Vladislav: Casts are not *supposed* to be smart! That's the whole point of a cast. It just blindly/dumbly casts the object to the specified type. It relies on you as the programmer to do your fact checking and make sure that the cast makes sense. You *need* one of the conversion methods in order to have any logic applied. You should think of a cast as telling the compiler to **pretend** that the object is actually of the specified type. It doesn't actually *change* the object's underlying type.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I believe I have officially started to forget everything I have learned from C/C++.

Comment: @Vlad, I donno C/C++ at all, but it's still very essential to always have in mind the differences between a direct cast `(Type)variable`, safe cast `variable as Type` and conversion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is that the `Cxx` "functions" in VB.NET **aren't actually functions**. In fact, they're more like *operators* that the compiler translates to what it determines is the "best-match" type conversion.

Paul Vick used to have a great article about this on his blog, but all those pages seem to have been taken down now. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) (which is mostly accurate here) says:

> These functions are compiled inline, meaning the conversion code is part of the code that evaluates the expression. Sometimes there is no call to a procedure to accomplish the conversion, which improves performance. Each function coerces an expression to a specific data type.

The options it has available to do so include a direct cast (such as: `(bool)var`), an attempt to cast (using the `as` operator), calling one of the methods defined in the [`System.Convert` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx), calling the applicable `Type.Parse` method, and maybe some other strategies.

There's no direct equivalent of this in C#: you have to do the compiler's thinking instead.

In this case, you'll almost certainly want to use the appropriate overload of the [`Convert.ToBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87ff1zdh.aspx) method because that particular method will have the necessary logic to convert the value into a `bool`. A direct cast won't work here.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [`System.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to be converting from one of the string values: "True", "true", "False", or "false", you should use Boolean.Parse.  Instead of trying to be "smart" about it, Parse will "fail fast" if it doesn't get what it expects.  By using a "smart" conversion when you don't really need it, you may mask errors at their source then have to track them down when they appear later in the code, which is usually more difficult.

Comment: Sometimes it IS necessary. Many case you know you expect either false or False; never something else.